# Как подсчитать сумму multiple select?

Tags: javascript

Может кто подскажет как подсчитать сумму нескольких пунктов в списке? и что бы потом можно было сложить с суммой другого списка и умножить на число, веденное клиентом
Вот что есть на данный момент

```js
  function changeText() {
    var rezultat1 = 1;
    var odin = document.getElementById('odin').value;
    var spisok = document.getElementById('spisok').options[document.getElementById('spisok').selectedIndex].value;
    var pokraska = document.getElementById('pokraska').options[document.getElementById('pokraska').selectedIndex].value;
    var shlifovka = document.getElementById('shlifovka').options[document.getElementById('shlifovka').selectedIndex].value;
    rezultat1 = parseFloat(odin);
    rezultat1 *= parseFloat(spisok) + parseFloat(pokraska) + parseFloat(shlifovka);
    document.getElementById('rezultat1').innerHTML = rezultat1;
  }
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
</head>

<body>
  <form class="rd-form rd-mailform" onsubmit="return false;">
    <div class="form-wrap checkselect">
      <label><b style="font-weight: bold;">Фанеровка</b></label>
      <select id="spisok" multiple class="form-select" onchange="changeText()">
        <option value="0" selected>Выбор</option>
        <option value="1">Шпон</option>
        <option value="2">МДФ</option>
        <option value="3">Прессование (одна сторона)</option>
        <option value="4">Прессование (две стороны)</option>
        <option value="5">Набор рубашки (прямая)</option>
        <option value="6">Набор рубашки (конверт)</option>
        <option value="7">Рубашка (инкрустация)</option>
        <option value="8">Оклейка кромкой</option>
        <option value="9">Шлифовка (черновая)</option>
        <option value="10">шлифовка (под покраску + грунт)</option>
      </select>

    </div>
    <div class="form-wrap">
      <label><b>Покраска</b></label>
      <select multiple id="pokraska" class="form-select" onchange="changeText()">
        <option value="0" selected >Выбор</option>
        <option value="1">Под лак</option>
        <option value="2">МДФ матовый (1 сторона)</option>
        <option value="3">МДФ матовый (2 стороны)</option>
        <option value="4">МДФ глянец (1 сторона)</option>
        <option value="5">МДФ глянец (2 стороны)</option>
      </select>

    </div>
    <div class="form-wrap">
      <label><b>Шлифовка</b></label>
      <select multiple id="shlifovka" class="form-select" onchange="changeText()">
        <option value="0" selected>Выбор</option>js
        <option value="1">до 50 м²</option>
        <option value="2">от 50 м²</option>
      </select>

    </div>
    <div class="form-wrap">
      <label><b>Укажите площадь м²</b></label>
      <input id="odin" class="form-input" type="number" placeholder="м²" value="" oninput="changeText()">
    </div>
    <div class="form-wrap">
      <label>Cтоимость у.е</label>
      <output id="rezultat1" class="form-input">&nbsp;</output>
    </div>

  </form>

</body>

</html>
```

JS для меня пока что дремучий лес..
Буду очень признателен любому совету.

Comment: Если какой то из ответов Вам помог, поставьте возле него галочку, что бы закрыть вопрос.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если я правильно понял Вам нужно сложить все выбранные значения из всех списков и потом умножить их на площадь? Если так тогда:

```
function changeText() {
  const odin = document.getElementById('odin').value;
  const spisok = document.getElementById('spisok');
  const pokraska = document.getElementById('pokraska');
  const shlifovka = document.getElementById('shlifovka');
  let total = 0;
  [spisok, pokraska, shlifovka].forEach(select => {
    [...select.options].forEach(option => {
      total = option.selected ? total + +option.value : total;
    });
  });

  if(odin) total *= +odin;

  console.log(total);
}
```

Comment: Спасибо огромное! Все работает!